# M-AUDIO fast track ultra 8R, audio loss and BSOD on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, audio-recording

M-AUDIO fast track ultra 8R dropping audio and causing windows stopcodes;

`DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`

`SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED`

With 6.1.9 driver on windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Rolling back the driver (to a time when the development team were more competent) fixes BSOD and audio dropping issue:

**1. Uninstall 6.1.9 driver**

- Control Panel > Programs > Uninstall a program
- Uninstall M-Audio FastTrackUltra8R Driver 6.1.9
- Reboot

**2. Install 6.0.10 driver from [Avid support website](http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/Download/Fast-Track-Ultra-8R-Drivers)**

Comment: Hopefully W10 will not reinstall the newer driver via windows update.